# Startup disk creator not reconizing arch linux iso

Tags: arch-linux, live-usb

I've been trying to install arch linux on a usb using startup disk creator, But whenever i try to select it, it never works. Is there anybody with the same problem? I downloaded the torrent directly from the arch linux site and i installed the latest version.

Comment: Arch iso is hybrid, meaning that you don't need any special tool to boot from USB, just use `dd if=arch.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M` on the linux terminal, or if you are on windows use Rufus.